# iOS Programming suggestion request REF sqlite/iOS app design

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I currently have an iOS app that provides a sqlite DB for the data backend to the app. This data is basically a list of information. Within this app I allow the users to mark records as bookmarked (sets a value in the DB). The problem here is when I post updates to the app via the internet (update through software) for data changes, the new downloaded DB wipes out the old one thereby removing the user customizations.

Any ideas on an easy method to search the current sqlite DB for those changes, store them temporarily, then import the new DB and transfer the changes to the new DB? Could I for instance use a Core Data element at the same time as using the sqlite DB backend? Maybe a key/value pair system?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

-LK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've done it is this:

For your new version, rename your .sqlite file e.g. foo-v2.sqlite.  Then, during initialization, check to see if the sqlite file for the old version is there - if so, copy over the necessary info and then delete the old sqlite file.

Comment: what I do for the update is copy the new DB to a temp file, IE tempfile.sql and then once I've verified the download went ok, I delete the old DB file and rename the tempfile to the one expected by the app. In this window I could do a few things I guess. The easiest would be to just open both sqlite files and run queries on them using a join of sorts, just trying to figure that out or if its even possible. Another thing I could do is before I delete the old DB file, load all of the records into key/value pairs and then replace the DB and do that process in reverse.. Thx for the suggestion..

Comment: If you don't want to do it via DB, you could also store info in the keychain or in iCloud.  Really depends on how much you have.  Generally tho, I think it's easier tp just open another connection and just sync the databases.

Comment: I got it solved, I used a NSMutableArray and a for loop, no prob, easy.. Thx for your feedback..